# How to get a different random sequence with OpenCV RNG?

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using OpenCV to create some random numbers. I initialize the generator as:

```
RNG rng( 0xFFFFFFFF );
```

And then to get a number:

```
rng.uniform( 0, 100);
```

But everytime I run my program the generated sequence is the same. How do I get a different sequence?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173468/how-to-get-a-different-random-sequence-with-opencv-rng?/) by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2014-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As stated in the doc

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=random%20number%20generator#rng

RNG takes a seed as arg. If you need a different sequence every time you have to initialize it with a different value every time, e. g. use time, thread id or some thing like this as seed....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1